# how do I solve unbalance stack in visual basic 2012?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2012, stack

This is error that I got

Additional Information: A call to PInvoke function 'cobawebcamsss!cobawebcamsss.Form1::SendMessage' has unbalanced the stack. This is likely because the managed PInvoke signature does not match the unmanaged target signature. Check that the calling convention and parameters of the PInvoke signature match the target unmanaged signature.

Here is the code :

Option Explicit On
Option Strict Off

Public Class Form1

```
Const WM_CAP As Short = &H400S
Const WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT As Integer = WM_CAP + 10
Const WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT As Integer = WM_CAP + 11
Const WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY As Integer = WM_CAP + 30
Const WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW As Integer = WM_CAP + 50
Const WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE As Integer = WM_CAP + 52
Const WM_CAP_SET_SCALE As Integer = WM_CAP + 53
Const WS_CHILD As Integer = &H40000000
Const WS_VISIBLE As Integer = &H10000000
Const SWP_NOMOVE As Short = &H2S
Const SWP_NOSIZE As Short = 1
Const SWP_NOZORDER As Short = &H4S
Const HWND_BOTTOM As Short = 1
Dim iDevice As Integer = 0
Dim hHwnd As Integer
' Declare Function
Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Object) As Integer
Declare Function SetWindowPos Lib "user32" Alias "SetWindowPos" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal hWndInsertAfter As Integer, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal cx As Integer, ByVal cy As Integer, ByVal wFlags As Integer) As Integer
Declare Function DestroyWindow Lib "user32" (ByVal hndw As Integer) As Boolean
Declare Function capCreateCaptureWindowA Lib "avicap32.dll" (ByVal lpszWindowName As String, ByVal dwStyle As Integer, ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer, ByVal nWidth As Integer, ByVal nHeight As Short, ByVal hWndParent As Integer, ByVal nID As Integer) As Integer
Declare Function capGetDriverDescriptionA Lib "avicap32.dll" (ByVal wDriver As Short, ByVal lpszName As String, ByVal cbName As Integer, ByVal lpszVer As String, ByVal cbVer As Integer) As Boolean

Private Sub LoadDeviceList()
    Dim strName As String = Space(100)
    Dim strVer As String = Space(100)
    Dim bReturn As Boolean
    Dim x As Integer = 0
    Do
        bReturn = capGetDriverDescriptionA(x, strName, 100, strVer, 100)
        If bReturn Then lstDevices.Items.Add(strName.Trim)
        x += 1
    Loop Until bReturn = False
End Sub

Private Sub OpenPreviewWindow()
    Dim iHeight As Integer = picCapture.Height
    Dim iWidth As Integer = picCapture.Width
    hHwnd = capCreateCaptureWindowA(iDevice, WS_VISIBLE Or WS_CHILD, 0, 0, 640, 480, picCapture.Handle.ToInt32, 0)
    If SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, iDevice, 0) Then
        SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_SET_SCALE, True, 0)
        SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEWRATE, 66, 0)
        SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_SET_PREVIEW, True, 0)
        SetWindowPos(hHwnd, HWND_BOTTOM, 0, 0, picCapture.Width, picCapture.Height, SWP_NOMOVE Or SWP_NOZORDER)
        btnSave.Enabled = True
        btnStop.Enabled = True
        btnStart.Enabled = False
    Else
        DestroyWindow(hHwnd)
        btnSave.Enabled = False
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub btnSave_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnSave.Click
    Dim data As IDataObject
    Dim bmap As Image
    SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_EDIT_COPY, 0, 0)
    data = Clipboard.GetDataObject()
    If data.GetDataPresent(GetType(System.Drawing.Bitmap)) Then
        bmap = CType(data.GetData(GetType(System.Drawing.Bitmap)), Image)
        picCapture.Image = bmap
        ClosePreviewWindow()
        btnSave.Enabled = False
        btnStop.Enabled = False
        btnStart.Enabled = True
        If sfdImage.ShowDialog = DialogResult.OK Then
            bmap.Save(sfdImage.FileName, Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp)
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub ClosePreviewWindow()
    SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_DRIVER_DISCONNECT, iDevice, 0)
    DestroyWindow(hHwnd)
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    LoadDeviceList()
End Sub

Private Sub btnStart_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStart.Click
    OpenPreviewWindow()
    btnStart.Enabled = False
    btnStop.Enabled = True
End Sub

Private Sub btnStop_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles btnStop.Click
    ClosePreviewWindow()
    btnStart.Enabled = True
    btnStop.Enabled = False
End Sub
```

End Class

and it got highlighted here when I break the operation

If SendMessage(hHwnd, WM_CAP_DRIVER_CONNECT, iDevice, 0) Then

please help, I am new in visual basic so I try to learn from others program but it didn't work, it is originally from visual basic 2010 and I copied it to visual basic 2012

Comment: Placing `Option Explicit` at the top of your file will cause the IDE to point out a lot of errors in this code to you. Anything that gets underlined needs to be looked at. The first thing I see is that your declaration of `SendMessage` is `(Integer, Integer, Integer, Object) As Integer` but you're using it in code as a Boolean return value (or implicitly casting it), and in other places you're passing a Boolean to the third parameter, which should receive an Integer. The error probably stems from the `lParam` being declared as an Object, when it should be an Integer.

Comment: A stack imbalance is caused by incorrect declarations, a mismatch between your Declare statement and the actual function signature.  And yes, they are not close to being correct.  Visit the pinvoke.net web site for better ones.

Comment: I've tried to change the lParam to Integer, but it hasn't changed, it has no error but the camera doesn't show up at all

Answer (score 1):

If you are getting an error about PInvoke..SendMessage, try replacing the line:

```
Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hwnd As Integer, ByVal wMsg As Integer, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Object) As Integer
```

With:

```
Declare Function SendMessage Lib "user32" Alias "SendMessageA" (ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As Integer, ByVal wParam As IntPtr, ByRef RECT As IntPtr) As IntPtr
```

After that, worked fine on my Win7 x64.

Comment: Could you please [edit] in an explanation of why this code answers the question? Code-only answers are [discouraged](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/148272/274165), because they don't teach the solution.